# animate li elements in specific manner

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am creating windows 8 like animation effect with jQuery. Please [check the fiddle first](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharjs/4PEAL/3/)!

Now, the dots (li elements) go properly from center to right. But they are not coming in properly from left to center.

I want fifth dot to reach first and then fourth and so on. Kindly suggest the solutions.

Currently, I am using this margin settings and duration in animate method :-

```
ml1=-1300;
ml2=-1000;
ml3=-750;
ml4=-550;
ml5=-400;

$('ul.dots2 li.'+1).animate({ marginLeft:ml1+'px'},0,'easeOutQuint');
$('ul.dots2 li.'+2).animate({ marginLeft:ml2+'px'},0,'easeOutQuint');
$('ul.dots2 li.'+3).animate({ marginLeft:ml3+'px'},0,'easeOutQuint');
$('ul.dots2 li.'+4).animate({ marginLeft:ml4+'px'},0,'easeOutQuint');
$('ul.dots2 li.'+5).animate({ marginLeft:ml5+'px'},0,'easeOutQuint');
```

Comment: Please note that you need to include jQuery core before any plugin that utilized jQuery such as easing plugin in your case. Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharjs/4PEAL/3/

Comment: yes, I noticed it, and have updated my fiddle also. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharjs/4PEAL/7/) please check

Comment: @Felix have u checked the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharjs/4PEAL/7/)?